# How to assert deeply in JSON with python

Tags: python, json, assert, assertion

I am trigerring an API call, and the server response is in JSON format.
the response looks like this:

```
{
"status": 0, 
"not_passed": 1, 
"why": [
    {
        "code": 229, 
        "reason": "some reason", 
     }
]
}
```

I need to assert two thing.
Status and reason
fro status I am using:

```
    r = requests.get_simple(url=Server.MY_SERVER, params=p)
data = json.loads(r.content)
assert data["status"] == 0
```

but it doesn't work for the 'reason', maybe because the 'reason' is deeper in the nested structure. How can I fix this one?

Comment: Show us the code where you attempt to access "reason", and show the error it produces, if there is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
assert data['why'][0]['reason'] == 'something'
```

Of course this assumes that `data['why']` exists, is a list, and contains a dict as its first element.

Comment: so  i am changing the 0 with 1 if the element is the second one?